# Show up only parts of prooftree on beamer frames

Tags: beamer, overlays, bussproofs

I tried to use prooftrees in a beamer file. Exists there an option to fade in each layer of the prooftree, without using several frames? In the code-frame below I used \visible<>{}, but it only displays the whole proof tree.
Best Nils

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{prooftree}
\visible<3-> {
\AxiomC{an axiom}
\LeftLabel{some label}}
\visible<2-> {
\UnaryInfC{some text}
\LeftLabel{another label}}
\UnaryInfC{more text }
\end{prooftree}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The \noLine command can be used to hide the lines, a working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{\uncover<3->{an axiom}}
\only<-2>{\noLine}
\LeftLabel{\uncover<3->{some label}}
\UnaryInfC{\uncover<2->{some text}}
\only<1>{\noLine}
\LeftLabel{\uncover<2->{another label}}
\UnaryInfC{more text }
\end{prooftree}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that the lines will be visible right from the beginning, you could move the overlay instructions inside the arguments of the `prooftree` macros:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{\uncover<3->{an axiom}}
\LeftLabel{\uncover<3->{some label}}
\UnaryInfC{\uncover<2->{some text}}
\LeftLabel{\uncover<2->{another label}}
\UnaryInfC{more text }
\end{prooftree}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Building on this ingenious answers, I used beamer's `\renewcommand<>` to automate and make the code nicer.

The `\ignorespaces` are to prevent spurious horizontal space on overlays where the lines are hidden ; the definition of `\noLine` ends with `\ignorespaces` as well.

The redefinition of `\buildNoScore`, which is used to make a "no-line", is to mimic the definition of `\buildSingleScore` and to avoid vertical space variations from overlay to overlay.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\renewcommand<>\LeftLabel[1]{\beameroriginal{\LeftLabel}{\uncover#2{#1}}}
\renewcommand<>\UnaryInfC[1]{\alt#2{\ignorespaces}{\noLine}\beameroriginal{\UnaryInfC}{\uncover#2{#1}}}
\renewcommand<>\BinaryInfC[1]{\alt#2{\ignorespaces}{\noLine}\beameroriginal{\BinaryInfC}{\uncover#2{#1}}}
\renewcommand<>\AxiomC[1]{\alt#2{\ignorespaces}{\noLine}\beameroriginal{\AxiomC}{\uncover#2{#1}}}

\def\buildNoScore{%
    \displace=\curScoreEnd%
    \advance \displace by -\curScoreStart%
    \global\setbox \myBoxD =%
        \hbox to \displace{\vbox{\vskip.4pt}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC<6->{}
\LeftLabel<6->{Ax}\UnaryInfC<5->{$\phi\land\psi\vdash\phi\land\psi$}
\LeftLabel<5->{E$\land_2$}\UnaryInfC<4->{$\phi\land\psi\vdash\psi$}
\AxiomC<7->{}
\LeftLabel<7->{Ax}\UnaryInfC<7->{$\phi\land\psi\vdash\phi\land\psi$}
\LeftLabel<7->{E$\land_1$}\UnaryInfC<4->{$\phi\land\psi\vdash\phi$}
\LeftLabel<3->{(I$\land$)}\BinaryInfC<2->{$\phi\land\psi\vdash\psi\land\phi$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```